# ¿Es posible conectarse a SQL Server Standar desde una aplicación de escritorio de una maquina fuera de la red?

Tags: sql-server, redes, vpn

Tengo instalado **SQL Server Standar sobre servidor Windows Server 2012R2** y estoy en la siguiente situación:

La empresa donde trabajo abrirá una nueva sucursal que esta a 1.4 Km de la principal, el hecho es que esta en proyecto (la colocación de dos antenas que aproximadamente demorara un par de semana). Sin embargo en la empresa se usa un sistema de escritorio con conexión a SQL y es apremiante que el sistema funcione en la sucursal lo antes posible, por ello intento abrir los puertos 1453 de mi router y acceder a mi base de datos por mi ip publico pero no lo he logrado, ¿es posible hacer lo que tengo pensado?. (la aplicación esta en Vb)

**Ya he probado haciendo uso de VPN y de igual manera me permite acceder desde la red pero no de un dispositivo externo.

Comment: ¿Qué servidor "SQL" usas? Dependiendo de qué servidor estés usando no basta con abrir un puerto (por ejemplo, MS SQL Server no lo permite). Una VPN es siempre la mejor solución para el caso de conectar dos sitios remotos de una misma empresa para acceder a servicios que están en el otro extremo.

Comment: Me corrijo: donde dije "no lo permite" quería decir que "hay que configurarlo para que lo permita". Aquí tienes una página donde explican cómo desactivar los puertos dinámicos de SQL Server: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-2017 ¿Podrías confirmarme que has habilitado en el firewall de Windows el acceso a MS SQL Server desde cualquier origen o, en su defecto, que has deshabilitado completamente el firewall?

Comment: Primero: los equipos tienen que poder verse. Que digas `fuera de la red` da a entender que estás en una red local externa a la red local de la BD. Tienes que ajustar todos los componentes en el camino entre los dos equipos: los firewall, equipos de seguridad si los hay (WPS, IPF), routers para enrutar correctamente. Además, hay que validar que se permitan conexiones desde la IP/red de la terminal remota. Además, debes revisar la seguridad de la conexión (que los datos viajen seguros, que nadie use ese puerto que abriste en el router para entrar sin permiso). Lo mejor es una VPN

Comment: Como estan conectadas las redes? por internet? como esta configurada tu red? permite acceder desde afuera? tenes una intranet? tenes puertos abiertos?

Comment: Tengo una intranet enlazada a un router, el puerto que quiero (1433) esta abiertos en el router, ademas agregue regla tanto para entrada y salida en firewal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La solución es la siguiente:

1. Asignar una ip a la máquina donde está la base de datos (que no esté en automático)
2. Configurar el protocolo de SQL Server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Crear reglas de entrada y salida en el firewall que permita conectarse por el puerto 1433
4. Abrir el puerto 1433 en el router redirigiendo las conexiones a la ip local de donde se encuentra la base de datos (previamente asignado)
5. Hacer ping al ip público para ver si hay respuesta.
6. Colocar la ip pública en reemplazo de donde va el nombre del servidor o ip fija, tengan en cuenta que la ip pública cada vez que se apaga el router cambiara asi que seria conveniente que lo enlacen a un dns de no-ip.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes Instalar una VPN y conectarte eso hará que parezca como red local y listo es la mejor solución y mas rápida según mi punto de vista

te dejo el link de como hacerlo con OPEN VPN:
[como instalar open vpn](https://whstatic.1and1.com/help/CloudServer/ES/d851521.html)

Comment: Siempre será mejor usar una VPN para esto. Es información del sistema, que no se sabe si viaja cifrada, y es una conexión a la BD. Esto, además, garantiza que no necesite lidiar con NAT y demás

Answer (score 2):

**Una situacion comun es que el servidor SQLServer tenga las conexiones remotas deshabilitadas.** 
Esto se da especialmente en servidores donde convive el servidor web y la  base de datos. Si ese es tu caso, tienes que habilitar las conexiones remotas. En caso contrario, aun con los puertos abiertos y habilitados, no podras acceder a tu servidor SQL.

**Accede a las propiedades de tu servidor y habilita las conexiones externas.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuacion tienes documentacion al respecto:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017#SSMSProcedure
- https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server/

Comment: Estas en lo cierto, olvide de mencionar ese punto.

Answer (score 1):

Para una situación similar, puesto que tengo un SQL Server 2016 en una máquina virtual Azure, lo que hice fue lo siguiente, en el servidor:

1. Habilitar el protocolo TCP/IP en el SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Revisar qué puerto usa SQL Server, ya que instalé SQL Server con una instancia nombrada.
3. Permitir conectividad por ese puerto en el Firewall de Azure.
4. Permitir conectividad por ese puerto en el Firewall del servidor Windows.
5. Habilitar la autenticación mixta en SQL Server.
6. Definir un LOGIN de tipo SQL, para conectividad, con los privilegios requeridos.

En el cliente, lo que hice fue:

1. Validé en el SQL Server Management Studio la conectividad, usando como Server Name lo siguiente: IP,PUERTO\INSTANCIA.
2. Conectarme con el usuario de tipo SQL definido previamente, no uno Windows.
3. Al tener conectividad, ya proceder a usar SQL Server.

Para aplicaciones, es importante descargar el ultimo ODBC disponible que tenga el fabricante y que permita conectividad hacia la versión de SQL Server requerida. Este driver lo puedes descargar desde https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339 y te soporta desde SQL Server 2008 hasta SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score -5):

si, solo necesitas poner la direccion ip del servidor seguido del puerto ejemplo:
     127.0.0.1,8080
en ese caso la ip de tu servidor, el puerto que ocupe, y el usuario de sql server con el cual te conectes[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado esta respuesta en las mismas circunstancias que propone el autor de la pregunta? Es decir, conectarte a una instancia de MS SQL Server que está funcionando en otra localización a través de la apertura de un puerto en el router. En caso afirmativo, ¿qué necesitaste configurar para conseguirlo?

Comment: Ya he intentado lo que mencionas pero no me ha funcionado. Esto me sirve solo si las dos maquinas están en la misma red, en mi caso aun no están y por ello quiero hacerlo abriendo el puerto

Comment: @RicardoRuizBenites, ¿podrías responder a mis preguntas? Ahora ya confirmo que usas MS SQL Server (deberías ponerlo en tu pregunta), pero necesito más datos referidos a la configuración de puertos dinámicos y, sobre todo, de la configuración del firewall.

Comment: Utilizo SQL Server 2014 Standar sobre un servidor Windows Server 2012 R2 además la configuración esta con el puerto 1433 y si abrí los puertos (entrada y salida) 1433 de firewall.