# Conectar BD de servidor a aplicacion de escritorio en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, servidor

Acabo de terminar mi aplicación la cual la desarrolle en C# utilizando windows forms, es una aplicación de escritorio, la cual trabaja con una base de datos local.

La aplicación se va a instalar en unas tiendas de ropa fuera de la empresa. Mi cuestión es: 
¿como puedo conectar la aplicación a la base de datos del servidor que se tiene en la empresa?. Ya que lo que pretendo es que los registros que se hagan en dentro de la aplicación puedan verse reflejados y almacenados en la base de datos del servidor. Recordando que hasta ahora solamente la tengo de forma local.

¿Como seria mi cadena de conexión para la base de datos del servidor? o ¿Que otra solución me recomiendan para este caso?

Gracias espero haberme explicado. Saludos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo primero sería tener el servidor publicado en web, con una ip publica que apunte al servidor que tienes en la empresa.

Después de eso, la cadena de conexión no cambiaría mucho de la que ya tienes, solo que en el nombre del servidor pondrías la ip pública.

sí usas un archivo de configuración se vería así:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cnxString" connectionString="Data Source=190.148.47.24<!-- Esta es la ip publica-->;Initial Catalog=MiBaseDeDatos;Integrated Security=False;User Id=USUARIO;Password=CLAVE" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>    
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Como puedes ver, la clave es configurar el acceso externo a tu servidor, podría ser a través del router o del dispositivo con el que se controle el tráfico de red en tu empresa.

La otra opción es migrar tu base de datos a la nube, podrías usar los servicios de Azure o Amazon WebServices.

Si quieres saber como configurar el acceso externo, puedes revisar esta pregunta [¿Es posible conectarse a SQL Server Standar desde una aplicación de escritorio de una maquina fuera de la red?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167756/es-posible-conectarse-a-sql-server-standar-desde-una-aplicaci%c3%b3n-de-escritorio-d?rq=1)

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Felipe, me ayudo bastante logre realizar la aplicacion!

Comment: Por seguridad te sugiero no abrir la base de datos SQL a Internet, en lugar de ello crear una VPN entre las sucursales y la matriz, hay routers "económicos" que hacen esta función configurándolos en unos pocos pasos, y muchas guías al respecto en Internet, suerte.

Comment: Hola Alejandro Medina, ¿si lo hice por conexión remota al servidor de SQL esta mal?, lo que pasa es que es la primera vez que trabajo una aplicación de escritorio usando un servidor. Saludos